# Meaning of "I'm funny like that"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Someone asked whether this sentence was grammatically correct:

> My best friend is a person who I can tell everything to.

A native English speaker replied:

> I would say it should be "who**m** I could tell everything to" or "to who**m**
> I could etc", but I'm funny like that.

What does "I'm funny like that" mean here?

Comment: What do you think it might mean? What research have you done? Which word specifically are you confused about?

Comment: It means “I have this eccentricity”.

Comment: ***I'm funny*** here means ***I'm unusual / atypical / peculiar***, and ***like that*** is just a vague reference to some aspect of the current situation (or something just spoken of) which *specifically* relates to ***the way in which I'm different to the norm***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original sentence is perfectly natural, though incorrect from a strict grammarian's perspective.

The native speaker is pointing this out, and giving the grammatically correct version.  But the speaker is also aware this is a kind of priggish thing to care about, and the phrase "I'm funny like that" acknowledges this in a lighthearted way.  It's equivalent here to: "I'm weird like that."

Comment: Could you please put it another way? I'm still a bit confused what "like that" is referring to.

Comment: "like that" means "in that way".  It's saying, "That (my compulsion to follow strict grammar) is an example of how I am weird."

Comment: I see. Why "but" is used before "I'm funny like that" then? 
This is my understanding of the reply so far: 
"I think/in my opinion your sentence would be grammatically correct if you used "whom" instead of "who" **but** I'm used to following strict grammar rules, this is how weird I am!". "But" here contradicts the first part of the sentence, doesn't it?

Comment: The "but" here is meant to qualify the first part of the sentence.... It implies something like this: "It's grammatically wrong, _but_ most people wouldn't care... only weirdos like me."

Comment: Thank you so much. The meaning is clear as day now.